# HTTP Request Canceled Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, http, requests

Estoy haciendo un control de sesiones para que no puedan haber dos sesiones simultaneas para el mismo usuario. Para ello se están usando unos servicios que registran, consultan y eliminan de una tabla de la DB la sesión.

Consulta y registro funcionan sin problema. El inconveniente sucede al intentar eliminar el registro y es porque el servicio lo consumo al hacer logout.

```javascript
  deleteSessionEIS(params){
    let headers = new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Origin': 'EIS',
    });
    return this.http.get(this.baseUrl + this.delete_session, {params, headers})
  }
```

```javascript
this.refTablesService.deleteSessionEIS({idUser: this.iComunication.user.userId}).subscribe(res => {
        let data = { "candidateId": this.iComunication.user.userId, "type_logout": "CLOSE_SESSION" }; //enum:[SESSION_TIMEOUT, ]    
        localStorage.setItem("isLog", "0");
        this.loginService.auditLogout(data, this.iComunication.user.userIP, this.iComunication.user.userMAC, Utils.decipherString(this.iComunication.user.officeCode), this.iComunication.user.userId, this.iComunication.user.displayName).subscribe(data => {
          //console.log ("LOG REGISTRADO")
        });
        this.modal.close();
        this.clean();
      })
```

La idea es que al hacer logout, consuma ese servicio que elimina el registro de la DB. Sin embargo, está sucediendo esto.

[image: Request Canceled]

Ahora, otro tema es que si se cierra el navegador por cualquier razón, detectar ese evento y consumir el mismo servicio. Para ello intente esto y tampoco funciona.

```javascript
  @HostListener('window:beforeunload')
  async ngOnDestroy() {
   this.refTablesService.deleteSessionEIS({idUser: this.userSession.userId}).toPromise()
  }
```

Les agradezco si me pueden ayudar

Muchas gracias

Comment: Que hace `this.clean()`? Me imagino que al cerrar se destruye el componente. No será que estas destrueyendo la comunicación con el código que tienes de `ngOnDestroy`?